# Why doesn't RSpec run these nested describe blocks in a shared_examples_for block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
shared_examples_for "test" do    

  specify {  } # RSpec executes this line.

  describe "nested" do

    specify { } # RSpec doesn't execute this line.

    describe "nested nested" do

      specify {  } # RSpec doesn't execute this line too.

    end
  end
end
```

Why does this happen? RSpec even doesn't recognise nested lines.
It shows just "1 example" even though there are 3 examples actually.
I'm using RSpec version 2.14.

Comment: it will run them if you actually put content and an assertion in them. You also have a syntax error - the last `do` should be an `end`.

Comment: The code I put is just a frame and not the actual coding.

Comment: then there's more to the problem than you're telling us - as the answer demonstrates, that will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is running because there's nothing to run! You declared a `shared_examples_for` block, but you haven't actually used the examples anywhere.

Use `it_behaves_like` to actually run the examples:

```
╭── jxf@polytope · 2014-04-16 · 23:07:32
│   ‹ruby:ruby-2.1.0@›
│   /tmp/foo
╰─▶ ψ cat test_spec.rb 
shared_examples_for "test" do
  specify { }
  describe "outer" do
    specify { }
    describe "inner" do
      specify { }
    end
  end
end

describe "naked" do
  it_behaves_like "test"
end
```

See how we're using an `it_behaves_like` block now? Let's run the examples:

```
╭── jxf@polytope · 2014-04-16 · 23:08:18
│   ‹ruby:ruby-2.1.0@›
│   /tmp/foo
╰─▶ ψ rspec test_spec.rb 
...

Finished in 0.00047 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: yes, I'm using `it_behaves_like` block in another place to call the shared examples I defined. The shared examples blocks are executed except the parts that I mentioned above.

Comment: @tkymtk Well, as my answer demonstrates, you must be omitting something from your description of the issue. As it's currently described, everything works fine.

Comment: Well, It goes well when I define `shared_examples_for` and `it_behaves_like` in a same file. But still doesn't work well when I separate them in two files.

Comment: @tkymtk It works fine in different files too. Please reproduce the issue and show us the code you're having the problem with.

Comment: Yeah, I think I figured it out. Some examples are doing bad things as I comment out some lines, tests goes well. Also it seems RSpec doesn't recognise nested examples when I execute them with a line specified at the end, like `rspec spec/***/**.rb:23`.